# Dimension of the eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am given the matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}

and I am asked to determine whether or not it is diagonalizable.

I know that the test for being diagonalizable involves: (1) checking whether or not the characteristic polynomial splits and (2) checking whether the multiplicity of eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ equals dim(${E_\lambda}_i$(L$_A$)) for all i.

The characteristic polynomial is (1-t)$^2$, which gives us an eigenvalue of 1 with a multiplicity of 2.

I am given that ${E_\lambda}(A)$ = { v $\in$ F$^n$: L$_A$(v) = $\lambda$v} = null(L$_A$ - $\lambda$I$_V$).

In attempting to compute the null(L$_A$ - $\lambda$I$_V$), I keep getting that the solution is

\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
0  \end{pmatrix}

to the following system

$$\left(\begin{array}{rl}1&2\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)-1 \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\end{array}\right),$$

but I am told that dim($E_1$) = 1. Can someone please help me? I don't understand what the vector is that gives us dim($E_1$) = 1.

Comment: Fact:  for **every** eigenvalue $\lambda$ you have:

$$1\leq \text{geomu}(\lambda)\leq \text{algmu}(\lambda)$$  If you find the geometric multiplicity of a supposed eigenvalue is zero, that implies that it either wasn't an eigenvalue in the first place, or that you made a mistake in calculation.

Comment: You have $\lambda = 1$. Hence $A - \lambda I = A - I = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 2\\0 & 0\end{matrix}\right)$. Now, solve the system $(A - I)\vec x = 0$. You get that $y = 0$, right? But **no restriction** on $x$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Since we are talking about L$_A$ though wouldn't we have something like the edit I made to my question above? Sorry I tried posting the system here but I don't know how to format it in the comments.

Comment: @King Tut Your system is correct. Now make the left hand side one vector.

Comment: @Alex I just put the LaTeX code into dollar symbols.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp So I obtain $(2y , 0)^t = (0 , 0)^t$. Since x doesn't appear this means that x is free to be anything? I see that 2y = 0, which means y = 0.

Comment: @King Tut Exactly. Also note that if $v$ is an eigenvector, also $tv$ is an eigenvector for each number $t$. Therefore, you are free to choose $x = 1$ so that $\vec x = \binom 1 0$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: @Alex Dubble dollar: $$ab=1.$$

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thanks! It's a lot clearer now. :)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, $L_A  - λ I_V$ = $\left(\begin{array}{rl}0&2\\0&0\end{array}\right)$.  So the non-zero unit vector that gets sent to zero by left-multiplying with this matrix is $\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)$.

You can check: $\left(\begin{array}{rl}1&2\\0&1\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)$.